# Swift: does not conform to ArrayLiteralConvertible

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass a dictionary into the Class parameter and I am running into the error of "Type "[String, Int]" does not conform to ArrayLiteralConvertible" when running the below code in Playground.

```
import UIKit

class Test : NSObject {
    var dict : [String:Int]

    init(param: [String:Int]) {
        self.dict = param
    }
}

var object : Test
object = Test(input: ["string", 10])
```

I was wondering if I am passing in the dictionary as a parameter wrong?

Very new to Obj-C/Swift so I am totally lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem there is that you have declared `dict` as a Dictionary not an Array. And the first parameter's name is `param` not `input`. You just have to use ":" instead of comma ","

```
import UIKit

class Test : NSObject {
    var dict : [String:Int]

    init(param: [String:Int]) {
        self.dict = param
    }
}

var object = Test(param: ["string": 10] )
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks, that typo wasted me 2 hours looking at init() for the ArrayLiteralConvertible Protocol. 

Got to be more careful next time :/

Comment: @Paul Deng You are welcome !!!